Relation between Zariski topology on $k^n$ and spec of coordinate rings
Let $k$ be any field and $X$ be a closed set in $k^n$ in the sense that it is a common zero set of some polynomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n].$ Let $k[X] = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I(X)$ denote the coordinate ring of $X$ where $I(X)$ is the ideal of polynomials which vanish on all of $X.$ Let $A= spec (k[X])$ with Zariski topology. I want to know the relation between $X$ and $A.$
I was thinking that $X$ is homeomorphic to subset of $A.$ My attempt is this :
Let $b = (b_i) \in X,$ consider the the maximal ideal $P_b = (x_1-b_1,\ldots, x_n-b_n)$ in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n].$ I think that $P_b$ contains the ideal $I(X)$ so then we can get a map $$ X \to A : b \mapsto P_b/I(X). $$
I am not able to show that $P_b$ contains $I(X).$ Is this even true for general fields?
If the above thing is not true then what is the actual relation?

That $\cal{P}_b$ contains $I(X)$ is trivial, because $b \in X$ implies $I(X) \subset I(b) = \cal{P}_b$. The problem is that you are here considering the space spec(${k[X]}$) and not the maximal-spectrum max-spec(${k[X]}$).  Also, if the field $k$ is not algebraically closed, there may be maximal (and hence, prime) ideals that are not of this form (i.e., given by a point).

There is no problem here, $X$ is straightforwardly homeomorphic to the set of $k$-rational points of $A$ under the standard inclusion stated in the post.

You seem to be assuming that the coordinate ring of $X$ is of dimension one. What if it is of higher dimension ? Then there would be points of $A$ that do not correspond to $k$-rational points (coming from maximal ideals). Or am I making some mistake ?

There is no assumption on the dimension of the coordinate ring of $X$. There is no reason to consider that - we're just taking a point $(b_1,\cdots,b_n)\in k^n$ and mapping it to the point $(x_1-b_1,\cdots,x_n-b_n)\in \operatorname{Spec} k[X]$. Of course there can be many points of $A$ that do not correspond to $k$-rational points - my only claim is that $X\subset k^n$ can be viewed as the subset of $k$-rational points of $A$ with the induced topology.

Thank you for clarifying.
